# .htaccess file not working: Error 404 PAGE NOT FOUND

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have trying to configure .htaccess file. The .htaccess file is given below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Require all granted
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/php_test_javascript_test_metor_Test_node/public/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$  /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The file should work and pass the request and the query to the page, but this is not happening rather I am getting `Error 404 PAGE NOT FOUND`.
**Can any one tell me what may be going wrong?**
I am using wamp when I tried to open the error.log file,it doesn't state any error regarding `Directory`,
My have set my virtual host as follows,

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
ServerName www.merisite.com 
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/php_test_javascript_test_metor_Test_node/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

Can cause a problem?

Comment: This does not make sense, you should get an error in the logfile upon startup of the http server process: `ServerAlias merisite.com*.merisite.com`

Comment: About your question: if that is the only host you configured then there simply is no difference in behavior.

Comment: Don't post a new question, _edit_ this one. There is an `edit` button below it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check AllowOverride setting on your web server config file and try to set **" AllowOverride All "**

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: how can I see the errors in .htacess files,its not showing up in apache_error.log